# MySQL Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, root, database-connection

I install MySQL Workbench 8.0.22 on windows. But I am not able to make a successful connection.What should I do to correct this?Although I enter the correct password, I got ***Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*** and cannot make db conection. Please help me. What I have done so far is,

- I delete  MySQL file in this path:

  %AppData%\MySQL
- Then I followed these steps for resetting root password:
  [Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

After I run this command

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
```

on CMD (running as administrator) I got:

```
2021-07-23T09:36:09.763074Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release. 
2021-07-23T09:36:09.764268Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 8892 
2021-07-23T09:36:09.765503Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous. 
2021-07-23T09:36:09.765528Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_unicode_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead. 
2021-07-23T09:36:09.835697Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started. 
2021-07-23T09:36:12.223043Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-07-23T09:36:13.527018Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060 
2021-07-23T09:36:13.756941Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery... 
2021-07-23T09:36:13.773592Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished. 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.104612Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed. 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.106154Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel. 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.174295Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@localhost'; Ignoring user 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.276943Z 7 [Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@localhost'; Ignoring user 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.278797Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1396  Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'. 
2021-07-23T09:36:14.284169Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

- I tried to connect db on MySQL Workbench 8.0:

When I double click on my database connection:

[image: Cannot Connect to Database Server]

Then I deleted all connections,

[image: Delete All Connections...]

and tried to create a new connection and click on the "Test Connection" button:

[image: Test Connection]

- I tried on MySQL Shell:

When I run this command then enter password for root user:

> \connect root@localhost

```
Creating a session to 'root@localhost'<br />
Please provide the password for 'root@localhost': **** <br />
MySQL Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

- I tried on CMD:

> mysqld --skip-grant-tables

```
2021-07-23T09:46:44.161756Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 14700 
2021-07-23T09:46:44.168273Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test 
2021-07-23T09:46:44.168472Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test 
2021-07-23T09:46:44.172258Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory) 
2021-07-23T09:46:44.173769Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting 
2021-07-23T09:46:44.173965Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

> mysql -u root mysql

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then I open CMD terminal, run as administrator, enter the command below to observe my MySQL port status (3306):

> netstat -a -b

```
TCP    [::]:3306              DESKTOP-MY:0      LISTENING
 [mysqld.exe]
```

Comment: There are several errors prompting in the logs you provided. Particulary in the first one, these stand out: `2021-07-23T09:36:14.174295Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@localhost'; Ignoring user ` and `2021-07-23T09:36:14.278797Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1396  Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'. `.  Try using an UPDATE query instead of ALTER in your mysql-init.txt file.

Comment: Thanks @Jetto Martínez, I ve changed the query as UPDATE but not works .Then I ve uninstalled everything related with MySQL and installed them again, now I can access as root user.